# Weird chrome-only 1px gap on my blue hover-state div

Tags: css

When you hover over a book on my site, http://seanbooks.tumblr.com/, the blue div seems to not quite cover the photo on the right, leaving a 1px gap. This only seems to happen in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why, but, on my screen, the images stretch to `351px` versus the container's `350px`, stretching out the container. If you set `position: absolute` on the image, it seems to play better.

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with the percentages not matching the pixel grid exactly :/ Glad this solution is close enough, though :D

Answer (score 1):

I think its because your width on .row .threecol is 22.05% and maybe chrome doesnt like trying to split the screen down that far. I changed it to 250px and it seems ok.

```
.row .threecol {
width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: That does seem to solve the stated problem, but note that then the site doesn't play well with a resized window. The percents actually do matter here.

Comment: ah yes you are right - I didnt see that they resize when the windows very small